# A differentiable function satisfying an inequality

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, differential

Let $f$ be a continuously differentiable function from $\Bbb{R}^n$ to $\Bbb{R}^n$ satisfying 
$||f(x)-f(y)||\geq||x-y||$ for all $x,y$.

Can we conclude that f is an open map?
What about closed map?

The only progress I made was to show $f$ is bijective.

Comment: Any bijective continuous map on $\mathbb R^{n}$ is a homeomoprhism.

Comment: I know the result for R. I use continuity + injective => monotonic
How do we do it for higher dimensions?

Comment: Not an easy result to prove. Books on algebraic topology contain a  proof.

Comment: But in this case, once you have bijectivity, isn't continuity of the inverse clear? Your assumption is literally that $||f^{-1}(w)-f^{-1}(z)||\leq ||w-z||$.